# Negative Modulos

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Problem Solved! Thanks.**

I see why -219 is not congruent to 219 mod 9; So I tried using the formula below to convert it to a positive number mod 9:

pm+r = #, where p is a number which makes the product pm slightly more negative than the #< and where m is the modulo. However, the result I got was not 6!

-219 = -22 * 10 + r

r = 1

Thanks!

Comment: Please be careful about using exclamation points.  In mathematics, they are usually used for factorials.

Comment: Yep, fixed it the sentence.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Why do you think that $-219$ and $+219$ "should" be congruent to the same number, and thus congruent to each other, modulo $9$? In general, the definition of "congruent modulo" tells you that two integers are congruent modulo $9$ if and only if their difference is divisible by $9$. In the case of $219$ and  $-219$, this would mean that the difference, $438$ "should" be divisible by $9$. Since $438$ isn't divisible by $9$, $219$ and $-219$ are not congruent modulo $9$.

Comment: Why are you dividing by $10$ rather than $9$?

Comment: I just realized this; Hah!

Comment: If I have two numbers both congruent to 0 mod a,b is there any simplifying method I can use? I.E., a = 0 mod b, and a = 0 mod c. Is there a trick I can use to find a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the definition.  $a \equiv b \mod{n}$ means that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$.

Since $219 = 24 \cdot 9+ 3$, $219$ has remainder $3$ when divided by $9$.  Hence, $219 \equiv 3 \pmod{9}$.

We could write, $-219 = -24 \cdot 9 - 3$, which yields the congruence $-219 \equiv -3 \pmod{3}$.  However, if we want a positive remainder, we want to find the closest multiple of $9$ to $-219$ that is less than $-219$.  This is $-25 \cdot 9 = -225$.  Hence, $-219 = -25 \cdot 9 + 6 \implies -219 \equiv 6 \pmod{9}$.

Answer (score 1):

-1 = 2 mod 3.

Or, if you prefer a visual representation, 5 minutes past the hour (1 mod 12) is a different time from 5 minutes to the hour (11 mod 12 = -1 mod 12).

Comment: Oh, I see; the direction changes the value! But still, how would we then find the value of negative modulo?

Comment: Keep adding the modulus value until you are positive!

Comment: e.g. -5 mod 12 = -5 +12 mod 12 = 7 mod 12.
       -22 mod 12 = -22 + 12 mod 12 = -10 mod 12 = -10 + 12 mod 12 = 2 mod 12.
Once you have the hang of it, it should seem routine.

Comment: Actually, I learned the formula pm+r = #, such that m is the mod, r is the remainder you're trying to find, and p is a number slightly more negative than the number. I tried to apply said formula, and the result is not 6: -22*10+r = -219, where r= 1, **not** 6.